# Generating PNG images with PHP

Tags: php, header, png

I am getting an error when I try to create `png` files. My code is like:

```
require_once('....');
header("content-type: image/png");

echo `$command`;
```

`PNG` file is generated by `$command` and the problem is that I include another PHP file and thus it can't display images. How would I be able to solve this?

Comment: if `$command` is just a string, and not .png data, that will cause the script to not display the image.

Comment: turn output buffering on before the new include and then off again, discarding the result. Also remove the ` quotes from $command.

Comment: What you probably have in your included file is a character - any character, it might be big or small - one whitespace would work. This messes up your whole header/png setup. Double-check your included script.

Comment: You might get a quicker answer if you [read this first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) then rewrite your question (or delete and re-post).

Comment: What is does the output look like if you change `image/png` to `text/plain`? Do you get random-looking binary data, an error message, blank output? That may show you what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show it as an image in the browser, you'll need to [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) it to be sent to the browser instead of just `echo`ing it.

```
$image = `$command`;
$b64 = base64_encode($image);
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' .$b64. '">';
```

Or you might try using [`imagepng()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) and related `GD` functions for this.